# What's the best approach to handle xcode projects with same codebase for multiple clients?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, ipad

I do have an iPad application which is customized for different customers in regards to color scheme, logos and other items.

I already created different targets where I defined #ifdef macros accordingly, and most variables are defined in a global.h file for easy maintanance.

Do you have any other useful suggestions I should consider at this time, especially as in the future there will be updates available - but not all new features will be avaialble to all clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you don't do that already, use the branching feature of your versioning system to handle different client needs, i.e. if one client wants an additional feature, don't (automatically) contaminate your master code base.

What you can also do is encapsulate all configurable features of your app. A very simple approach would be to create a configuration .plist or other kind of XML where you can easily configure adaptable features.

Mainly, if it's possible, try to extract all customizable features out of the primary code base. Load customizable data from easily editable files like XMLs, to make sure you don't accidently break something while configuring for a client.

Answer (score 0):

You could totally abstract out all of the customizable elements and create a library of the remaining code.  Each customer's App would then just instantiate that library and feed in their own customized elements.  That way you don't have to change any code when you build the App for a new customer.  You also get the benefit of having all the changes between customers located in one area and it also makes the code more testable.

If a customer doesn't get a feature, then you just feed in a null value (or equivalent)

This ideas is basically [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

Answer (score 0):

I like to convert reusable components into frameworks. This way you can expose customizable options and hide all of the complex code.

Another option would be to create a workspace. This would allow you to open projects within it  and share their assets with the main workspace files.